# check if hidden equals true or false jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

i've got this

```
$('#div').attr("hidden", true);
```

i tried:

```
var a = $('#div').attr("hidden");
var b = $('#div').attr("hidden").val();
var c = $('#div').hidden;
var a = $('#div').disabled;
```

i just want to know whether hidden is true or false. does anybody know? my research results are all about forms and inputs.

Comment: what does "hidden" mean? i didn't know there was a "hidden" attribute for a div.

Comment: What are you trying to do? hide the div or store a value in the attributes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

attribute will never be `true`, it can have strings only.
 jQuery has the `data` functions for objects other than strings:

```
$('#div').data("hidden", true);      // set the "hidden" data
var flag = $('#div').data("hidden"); // get the "hidden" data (true)
```

If you wanted to hide the `div`, use `.hide()`:

```
$('#div').hide();
```

And you check if the div is visible with `:visible` \ `:hidden`

```
$('#div').is(':visible'); // Or $('#div').is(':hidden')
```

Comment: I'd recommend using data-hidden instead of just hidden for html5 compatibility, and using it to jquery.data better. Also you can use numerical representation 0(false), 1(true)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could use

```
$('#div').toggle(showOrHide);
```

where showOrHide is a bool of true of false to hide or show.

This is the same as doing

```
if ( showOrHide == true ) {
  $('#div').show();
} else if ( showOrHide == false ) {
  $('#div').hide();
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

i think you mean jquery  [visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

```
.is(':visible')
```