# Hide static (or hardcoded) text in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML page containing some hardcoded/static text.
The text string does not have any class/id/name. It's just there.
How to hide it on page load?

P.S: I really hope this is not a repeat question. I have done my 'homework'.

Comment: i had a similar question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008312/check-if-hidden-equals-true-or-false-jquery

Comment: Without seeing the markup it is impossible to give an answer. The text is not just "there", for sure - it must be inside some kind of element in the page structure.

Comment: Do you have the option of enclosing it in a span tag or are you restricted to working with that specific 'naked' text?

Comment: @Shah: I cannot change the page code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide an element that doesn't have any direct identifiers by using a CSS selector which examines structure. You didn't post your markup, so it's impossible to give an exact solution.

### Example 1

HTML

```
<body>
    <section>
       <div>Div I want to hide</div>
    </section>
</body>
```

CSS

```
SECTION > DIV { display: none; }
```

There are many permutations of this pattern and many selectors available.

See: [CSS2 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) (very wide support) and [CSS3 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) (supported in most newer browsers).

### Example 2

Here's a more complex example:

HTML

```
<div id="foo">
    <ul>
        <li>Hide this item</li>
        <li>Don't hide this</li>
        <li>Don't hide this</li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* hide the first child of any UL which is a direct descendant of #foo */
#foo > UL > LI:first-child { display: none; }
```

Comment: Useful in general. Though I won't be able to use it. : )

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, `display: none`? That'd be the easiest way. Or you could go with javascript once the page has loaded.

Comment: So, how does the OP get the element in javascript in order to set this property?

Comment: DOM traversal, but as you pointed out in your comment on the question, without knowing the markup I can't give an example

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about doing it with javascript, you would have to do a `window.onload` and set the style.display = "none"; but that would require an id/class/some way to reference it (there are ways to reference it without them but it's a lot better style to just give it an id/class. The function would look something like this.

```
window.onload = function() {
```

`document.getElementById("text").style.display = none;` 
`};`

where your string has an id of "text"

Although if you are determined to have the text just appear as none on startup, why not just set the style/css to originally to have a display of none?

Comment: Thanks @aug but I won't be able to use this one.